# Unable to synch my iOS app with Crashlytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I have followed the instructions from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0 but I am still unable to synch my app on Crashlytics.

Crashlytics keeps loading but nothing happens. Like in the image below.

Note: My project previously had crashlytics with Fabric.

[image]

I also received an e-mail form Firebase that indicates that something is going wrong with an API KEY restrictions. But I was unable to find any restrictions on the API's connected to the Firebase for this project.

[image]

Comment: Did you add Firebase Crashlytics via Swift Package Manager or Cocoa pods?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to switch the API keys from those in a tutorial or developer guide?

Comment: I have enabled the same API key that exists in Google-Service-Info.plist